# Database caching with Spring Cloud (or maintaining consistent lists between microservices in general)

Tags: spring, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cache

I'm quite new to Spring Cloud and microservices in general, and this is a concept I'm struggling to understand.

Let's say I have microservice X which connects to a mongo database, and I've enabled Spring caching using the `@EnableCaching` annotation. I have set things up so that whenever I save/persist an object to mongo, it also gets added to my cache (`@cachePut`), and similarly when I remove an object from mongo it gets removed from the cache (`@CacheEvict`).

That all works fine if I have a single instance of microservice X, but what happens if I stand up 50 instance of microservice X? Do they all share the same cache, if so how does that work? If they all have their own individual caches, what happens if objectA gets added to one instance's cache and the database, then removed from the database by another instance? objectA will still be in the first instance's cache even though it has been removed from mongo.

Hopefully someone can clear this up

Comment: You should not use in-process caching, but instead use distributed caching for your Spring application e.g. with Memcached or Redis.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it